# Can't see all tables in datasource

Tags: oracle, birt

I'm using Birt 3.4.1.  I was able to create a datasource.. but I can't see all the tables in my database.  When I try to create a database  I see 1/3 of my tables in the Oracle 10g database.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the tables in the same schema?